# maven-ear-plugin "Processing overlay" very slow

Tags: java, maven

When running `mvn install` the maven-ear-plugin "Processing overlay" is very slow.

For example this specific case: https://dev.arcbees.com/gaestudio/

What are the possible reasons that would cause "Processing overlay" to be delayed?

Comment: First please show the pom files your are using best is a reference to a github project or similar...and furthermore what do you understand under `very slow` ? What does this exactly mean ? How many WAR`s are you processing ?